# Derivation of dynamic nonlinear equation of motion of cantilever beam

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, continuum-mechanics, non-linear-systems, structural-beam

Is it possible to derive the EOM of an [inextensible cantilever beam](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=inextensible+cantilever+beam) without using any kind of variational principle I mean is it possible to derive it from Newton's law only?

Note: of course This should be the nonlinear case i.e large deflection case

Comment: this is a solved problem. google on free vibratory response of a cantilever beam.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can take a differential element and do a balance of forces and moments. Then, apply Euler-Bernoulli hypotheses equate that to mass times acceleration and get what you want. Some of that is done in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory).